# Daily matrix report without data

Tags: reporting, analytics, matrix

Is it possible to create a matrix report without having records for one of the columns?

For example: I have a matrix report with columns grouped daily for a custom date field; I have records for day 1, day 2 and nothing for day 3.
I need to show day 3 in the report with a 0 value in the summarized fields.

It should be something like this image:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, this cannot be done in Salesforce reports.

In general, Salesforce reporting isn't good at showing you what is missing.  I have a similar report.  Even though I give it a range of 9/1/2014 to 10/6/2014, I don't get a column for each day.  The report only shows me columns where there is at least one date present for the field selected as the column.

**edited to add**

I just remembered another project I worked on that applies here.  Making sure attendance gets entered is something my organization spends a lot of time on.  We track attendance in Salesforce.  How can we report on what is not there when Salesforce isn't good at that?  We used to export a matrix report to Excel.  This had limitations; the foremost was that the results were not in Salesforce.

Our "in-Salesforce" solution is to run scheduled jobs that check each site for each open day.  Where there's missing attendance, a record for the site/day is created (custom object).  Now we can report affirmatively on what is missing.  A second scheduled job sets the missing attendance records to "resolved" status if the attendance has been entered.  This isn't simple, but it is a sufficiently important issue to us that it was well worth doing,

Comment: In my case, we also use something like this. I have a scheduled job that creates a record per day for each record of another custom object which is almost 5k records per day. And now we are facing a problem with data storage.